# How to get any file or directory ico use rust in windows?

Tags: rust

There are some way to get any file or directory ico use rust in windows?

I can't find any solution in google and stackoverflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use the `winapi` crate to get the icon associated with a file or directory on Windows.

Comment: You might be looking for the crate `systemicons`

Comment: @Ponchy systemicons create only can get the default system icons, I also want to get the icon of my newly installed program.